# JOINING table using Sub Query

Tags: mysql

I am trying to JOIN two tables both tables has one common column name "campaign_id". I have some other queries too. After executing other queries i have the result

```
SELECT campaign_id,  COUNT(fstaff_id)
FROM timetable
WHERE fstaff_id IN (SELECT fstaff_id FROM fstaff WHERE salarygrade>2)
GROUP BY campaign_id
HAVING COUNT(fstaff_id)>2;
;
```

using abovecode i got a result like this ..

```
 campaign id | Campaign Count 
----------------------------------
 1           |      10 
 2           |      15
```

Now I want the campaign name as well like this

```
 campaign id | CampaignName | Campaign Count 
--------------------------------------------------
 1           |friday sale   |      10 
2           |XYZ offer  |      15
```

I have a table named "campaign", which has column "campaign_id" and "campaign_name"
I am trying this code but not working

```
<pre>
SELECT timetable.campaign_id, campaign_name, COUNT(fstaff_id)
FROM timetable

JOIN campaign ON timetable.campaign_id=campaign.campaign_id

WHERE fstaff_id IN (SELECT fstaff_id FROM fstaff WHERE salarygrade>2)

GROUP BY timetable.campaign_id
HAVING COUNT(fstaff_id)>2;

;
```

If i use

```
SELECT timetable.campaign_id...
and 
GROUP BY (timetable.campaign_id)
```

I get error code 1055

but if i remove timetable from select and group by and use

```
SELECT campaign_id.....
GROUP BY (campaign_id)
```

then i get error code 1052

Please help me with this to add Campaign Name beside Campaign Id from campaign table.

Comment: Group by campaign_id and campaign_name - if that fails add sample data and expected output as text to the question.

Comment: Group by campaign_id and campaign_name  worked